# Duvida sobre query mysql

Tags: mysql

Realizei uma Query no banco MySql, mas percebi que trouxe valores duplicados. Não entendi em qual ponto da Query pode estar o problema, segue a query.

```
select  usuarios.nome as usuario,forma_pagamento.nome as forma, status.nome as statu, viagens.valor 
as viagemValor,  viagens.distancia as km, viagens.valor_extra as extra, viagens.data_criado as dtcriado,
entregadores.nome as entregadorNome
from viagens 
inner join entregadores
on (viagens.entregadores_id= entregadores.entregadores_id)
inner join usuarios
on (viagens.usuarios_id= usuarios.usuarios_id)
inner join forma_pagamento
on (viagens.forma_pagamento_id=forma_pagamento.forma_pagamento_id)
inner join status
on (viagens.status_id=status.status_id)
where empresas_id= 11 and viagens.deleted = 0
and viagens.data_criado > '2018-03'
```

Comment: Para responder precisaríamos saber como está definido o modelo de dados. Muito provavelmente não está tuuuuudo duplicado, deve haver uma informação que está gerando o produto cartesiano. Muito provavelmente essa `entregadores`. É possivel ter mais de um entregador para uma viagem?

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade não há problema na query, para que os dados não sejam duplicados é necessário adicionar o `distinct` no `select`. Dentre os diversos motivos para isso ocorrer(Exibição de dados duplicados) os que mais vejo são tabelas com relacionamento `1 para muitos` e `muitos para muitos`, segue como sua query deve ficar:

```
select distinct
    usuarios.nome as usuario,
    forma_pagamento.nome as forma, 
    status.nome as statu, 
    viagens.valor as viagemValor,  
    viagens.distancia as km, 
    viagens.valor_extra as extra, 
    viagens.data_criado as dtcriado,
    entregadores.nome as entregadorNome
from viagens  
inner join entregadores on (viagens.entregadores_id= entregadores.entregadores_id)
inner join usuarios on (viagens.usuarios_id= usuarios.usuarios_id)
inner join forma_pagamento on (viagens.forma_pagamento_id=forma_pagamento.forma_pagamento_id)
inner join status on (viagens.status_id=status.status_id)
where empresas_id= 11 
    and viagens.deleted = 0
    and viagens.data_criado > '2018-03'
```